# Arcane Trickster Multiclass - Spell Preparation

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, multi-classing

I'm making level 5 character, Rogue 3 (Arcane Trickster) Wiz 2 (Conjuration).

I can't find anything in the handbook explaining how (if?) the Arcane Trickster needs to prepare his spells in any way.

The way I read it, I would end up with my Wiz-3-worth of 'prepared spells', and then all of my Arcane Trickster spells would just be 'always prepared'. Is this correct?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> **Spells Known and Prepared.** You determine what spells you know and can prepare for each class individually, as if you were a single-classed member of
>   that class. - *PHB*, p164

An Arcane Trickster 3/Conjurer 2 knows the following:

**From Conjurer**

- Three cantrips from the Wizard list
- Six 1st-level Wizard spells (gained at level 1)
- Two 1st-level Wizard spells (gained at level 2)
- Anything he's found scrolls for.

Note that because you consider the classes individually when determining spells known, the character *could not* select 2nd-level spells at level 2, even though the character may have the slots (as described below).

The character can prepare (Conjurer Level)+(INT Mod) spells from the Wizard list as a Conjurer.

**From Arcane Trickster**

- *Mage Hand* plus two cantrips from the Wizard list.
- Three 1st-level Wizard spells, two of which must be enchantment or illusion.

All of the spells gained from Arcane Trickster are considered prepared at all times.

> **Spell Slots.** You determine your available spell slots by adding together all your levels in the bard, cleric, druid, sorcerer, and wizard classes, half your levels (rounded down) in the paladin and ranger classes, and a third of your fighter or rogue levels (rounded down) if you have the Eldritch Knight or the Arcane Trickster feature. Use this total to determine your spell slots by consulting the Multiclass Spellcaster table. - *ibid*

The only part of multi-classing where the two classes have anything to do with each other is in determining spell slots, as quoted above. In the case of an Arcane Trickster 3/Conjurer 2, the character has the spell slots of a third level caster, because (3/3)+2=3. This means the character has four 1st-level and two 2nd-level slots.

If the character has a spell that can be cast in a higher level slot for added effect, the character can do so. Even spells without an added benefit can be cast from a higher level slot, they just don't do any more than they would out of the slot they normally use. Either way, the character *doesn't know any 2nd-level spells* despite having slots for them.

Comment: +1 - Coming from someone who's playing a Wizard/Druid, I can confirm this. It's a bit confusing because it seems like you have a TON of spells, especially when you have Arcane spells prepared, and druid spells known. But you're limited to Spell Slots based on level. and as described you'll usually have slots without spells of that level.

Comment: @JohnGrabanski Indeed... you just have to pick spells that have a bigger effect from bigger slots to make use of them. I've got a Bard/Sorcerer that doesn't have many big blasty spells, because it's not her style. She's devastatingly surgical with the spells she does have. She can seriously ruin a single person or small group's day.

Comment: Thank you for including the part about not actually knowing 2nd level spells.  I probably would've overlooked that.

Comment: This question was not asking about spells known or spell slots. It was asking about spells prepared. You didn't answer the question. Like the OP, I've been assuming the rogue spells are always prepared, but I'm looking for confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

#### Prepared spells

The *Arcane Trickster* has a number of spells known (see chart on PHB p.98). Those spells (which have to be either enchantment or illusion spells from the wizard spell list) are as you call it 'always prepared'.

The downside is, that you can only switch **one** of those spells when you take a level in *Arcane Trickster*. So choose wisely.

The *Wizard* can prepare a number of spells **from his spellbook** equal to his **INT-Mod + wizard level**. Those spells have to be in your spellbook.

When preparing spells, you prepare them "for each class individually, as if you were a single-classed member of that class." *(PHB p.164 **spells known and prepared**)*

#### Spell Slots

You would have 2 levels of **wizard** and 3 levels of **arcane trickster** to determine your spell slots. So you would have to use the 3rd row (1*wizard levels + 1/3*arcane trickster levels (rounded down)) on multiclass-spellcaster spell slots table on PHB p. 165.

Comment: 1/3*rogue (arcane trickster) level rounded down. As seen on PHB p. 165.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the other answer as saying 1/2.  You both agree 1/3.  Apologies for the noise.